# Period и как его суммировать (Java)

Tags: java

при суммировании периодов получаю результат - 60д. 19м. 2г. (год на важно, с ним все ок)
помогите пожалуйста решить задачу - как все это дело переделать что выводило информацию в виде дней не более 31, месяцев 12

```
result_sum.setText(period.plus(period1).plus(period2).plus(period3).plus(period4).plus(period5).plus(period6).plus(period7).getDays() +
                        " д. " + period.plus(period1).plus(period2).plus(period3).plus(period4).plus(period5).plus(period6).plus(period7).getMonths() +
                        " м. " + period.plus(period1).plus(period2).plus(period3).plus(period4).plus(period5).plus(period6).plus(period7).getYears() + " л. ");
```

Comment: Да возьмите любую дату, добавьте к ней все свои периоды, а потом посчитайте разность с исходной датой. Всё равно куча дней в дни-месяцы-годы однозначно не переводится...

Comment: @AzizUmarov Уточните, в чём именно, в каком моменте я ошибаюсь... я ж собственно про то и говорю, что пересчёт дней в дни-месяцы-годы зависит от базовой даты. Тем более что скорее всего у автора стоИт задача расчёта суммарного стажа или типа того - а вот тут однозначно надо опираться на некую начальную дату, которая просто обязана быть в данных.

Comment: @Akina удалил комент прочитал конец только.

Comment: @Akina любую дату использовать можно конечно. (+- высокосные годы)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Period period = Period.of(0, 0, 0);
    Period period1 = Period.of(0, 1, 25);
    Period period2 = Period.of(0, 1, 14);
    Period totaPeriod = period.plus(period1).plus(period2);

    System.out.printf(
        "Total period Days = %d, Months = %d", totaPeriod.getDays(), totaPeriod.getMonths());
    // Total period Days = 39, Months = 2
    System.out.println();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    today = today.plusDays(totaPeriod.getDays()).plusMonths(totaPeriod.getMonths());
    totaPeriod = LocalDate.now().until(today);

    System.out.printf(
        "Total period Days = %d, Months = %d", totaPeriod.getDays(), totaPeriod.getMonths());
    //Total period Days = 8, Months = 3
  }
```

Идея такая что бы правильно определить месяцы и дни вам нужно опираться от какой либо даты, дабы знать количество дней в следующем месяце/годе ....

Comment: спасибо от души, все получилось) я уже думал костыли пилить.

Comment: @VaSeBa если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный. Под стрелками.